# Doesn't create a database table from my model baseclass

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to build a logging application that stores date, exercise type, duration and comments in a database. It renders the form as i expect it but it does not create the database table from my base class. I just got stuck and hope anyone can help me what's going wrong.

```
CHOICES = [
        (None, 'Choose Exercise'),
        ('Aerobics', 'Aerobics'),
        ('Box & Kick', 'Box & Kick'),
        ('Circle Training', 'Circle Training'),
        ('Core', 'Core'),
        ('Afrodance', 'Afro Dance'),
        ('HIT', 'HIT'),
        ('StepUp', 'StepUp'),
        ('Zumba', 'Zumba')]


class AerobicExercise(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default='YYYYMMDD')
    duration = models.DurationField()
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    exercise = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exercise


class SplitDurationWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (forms.NumberInput(attrs=attrs),
                   forms.NumberInput(attrs=attrs),
                   forms.NumberInput(attrs=attrs))
        super(SplitDurationWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            hours = value.seconds // 3600
            minutes = (value.seconds % 3600) // 60
            seconds = value.seconds % 60
            return [int(value.days), int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)]
        return [0, 0, 0, 0]


class Duration(MultiValueField):
    widget = SplitDurationWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.IntegerField(),
            forms.IntegerField(),
            forms.IntegerField(),
        )
        super(Duration, self).__init__(
            fields=fields,
            require_all_fields=True, *args, **kwargs
        )

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if len(data_list) == 3:
            return timedelta(
                hours=int(data_list[0]),
                minutes=int(data_list[1]),
                seconds=int(data_list[2])
            )
        else:
            return timedelta(0)


class AerobicForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AerobicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['duration'] = Duration()
        date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today())

    class Meta:
        model = AerobicExercise
        fields = '__all__'
        localized_fields = ('date',)
        widgets = {
            'comment': Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'The highlight of this workout was...'}),
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't create the table migrations when you run `manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: For some strange reason it didn't but after deleting my migrations folder and running "python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb" everything work now! :-)

Comment: Once you make a new model or edit an existing one, you have to first run `makimigration` in order to create the migration files. Then you have to run `migrate` to apply those migrations to your current db setup. @Niklas

Comment: I did exactly that but it didn't work for me. :S